# iOS safari transform pixelated

Tags: css, css-transforms

Trying to achieve slanted design using `:before`.

It is not smooth in **iPad landscape** view.

[image]

Below  CSS is applied.

```
.contact {
  background: #0067AC;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.contact:before {
  background: #0067AC;
  content: "";
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -30px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-2deg);
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` in `.contact:before`

Comment: Fixed the issue in ipad hack with `    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #0067AC;`